# Why margin doesn't work inside the block?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class='block'>
  <div class='container'></div>
</div>

.block {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
}
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

I can not understand why margin does not work inside the block?

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/39yy7a0q/

Comment: The margin is working, but you are experimenting with margin-collapse function of CSS.

You can solve this kind of problems defining a border or a padding. 

See this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/39yy7a0q/7/

    .block {
        display: block;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background: black;
        border:1px solid black;
    }

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/39yy7a0q/8/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing  If you need cause (and you've asked 'why') - check this article....

Comment: You could set `.block` overflow to hidden or add a small padding. https://jsfiddle.net/39yy7a0q/10/

Comment: The problem is your display property of container class. INLINE-BLOCK An element set to inline-block is very similar to inline in that it will set inline with the natural flow of text (on the "baseline"). The difference is that you are able to set a width and height which will be respected. DISPLAY:BLOCK They are usually container elements. Also text "blocks" like <p> and <h1>. Block level elements do not sit inline but break past them. By default (without setting a width) they take up as much horizontal space as they can. DEMO: jsfiddle.net/39yy7a0q/11

Answer (score -2):

Try below css. I have added position to `.container`, and adjusted `margin` value as it should relevant to parents width. https://jsfiddle.net/39yy7a0q/4/

```
.block {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: black;
}

.container {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
    margin: 35px;
}
```

Comment: The problem is your display property of container class.

INLINE-BLOCK

*An element set to inline-block is very similar to inline in that it will set inline with the natural flow of text (on the "baseline"). The difference is that you are able to set a width and height which will be respected.*

DISPLAY:BLOCK
They are usually container elements. Also text "blocks" like `<p>` and `<h1>`. Block level elements do not sit inline but break past them. By default (without setting a width) they take up as much horizontal space as they can.

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/39yy7a0q/11/